# Open user's browser, or switch to the appropriate tab if the website is already opened

Tags: objective-c, macos, url, nsworkspace

In my Objective-C app, I use this code to open a website in the user's browser:

```
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://blah.com/"]];
```

This works fine. However, there is one small problem; if the user already has opened "blah.com" in his webbrowser, calling this unncessarily creates a new tab.

It would be better user experience if it simply switched to the existing tab in those cases.

Is there a way to do this? Note that I would also want to switch to the existing tab if the tab is on a subpage of "blah.com", like "blah.com/some/page.html".

Comment: I'd love to be able to do this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `-[NSWorkspace openURL:]`.  If you know that the user is using Chrome or Safari, you can do it by running some AppleScript.